# Kubuntu 19.10: Screen flickers after waking up from suspend mode

Tags: display, suspend, kubuntu, amd-graphics, asus

### Issue:

Screen starts flickering whenever my laptop wakes up after a sleep or blank screen.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Let your laptop go to sleep or let its display turn blank.
2. After wake-up, the display starts flickering.

### My machine:

I am using [ASUS FX505DT](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/specifications) which has KDE and i3wm installed.
**PS:** *I also used to face this issue on my previous Ubuntu 19.10 install with Unity.*

**Specifications:**
Processor: AMD® Ryzen™ 5 3550H Processor
Graphics Card: AMD Vega 8 Graphics Card
Graphics Card: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 , with 4GB GDDR5 VRAM

> I know this question might seem like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/883067/ubuntu-16-10-screen-flicker-after-monitor-wake-up, but I'm still posting this question because no solution or workaround are fixing this for me.

*Update 1:* I have funneled down the cause for this issue. It seems to happen only after my laptop wakes up from being suspended.
*Update 2:* I can also trigger this bug by switching my display mode from 120Hz to 48Hz. The screen starts flickering as soon as I switch to 48Hz. Reverting back stops the flickering.

Comment: expanding on *Update 2* ... what happens if you set the display mode to 120 Hz after the laptop wakes up?

Comment: @jsotola I tested it right now and it doesn't stop the flickering

Comment: what happens if you do the switch to 48 Hz, then to 120 Hz?

Comment: No change in particular. Though the decrease in refresh rate is perceptible.

Comment: so the flickering is different from the 48 Hz refresh rate flickering

Comment: Yes, 48Hz flickering happens every 10-12s while 120Hz flickering happens every 3-4s.

Comment: I feel I should make a comment, maybe it will help someone ivestigate further:
I have exactly the same laptop and exactly the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. This happens both while using nvidia-driver-435, nvidia-driver-430 and nouveau driver.
I tried changing refresh rate with xrandr --output MONITOR --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60 xrandr --output MONITOR --mode 1920x1080 --rate 120
Sometimes it helps, sometimes not, sometimes it makes the problem appear even if it was not there (same as if I let the laptop go to sleep and wake up). I guess this counts as soft restart of a monitor. FYI: I h